# How to launch google map navigation with multi stop through my android app

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I want to launch google map navigation with two destinations,example my last destination is 'x' and while i'm going for that in middle i want to go to place 'y',so i want to show navigation from my current place to 'y' place and finally 'x' place,so how would i do in my app any suggestions please.

Comment: This question is too broad; you have not mentioned what technologies you are using, nor have you provided any evidence of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here how you can do it.

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

For more please visit:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Comment: i want to show navigation not for one destination from x to y, y to z

Comment: @shra1 The above Intent will request turn-by-turn navigation to Taronga Zoo, in Sydney Australia: Places are just give for example.